# How to clear recent history in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, history, gnome-activity-journal

First, I know how to do it in Ubuntu. I could use Activity Log Manager to clear recent history.

However, it does not work on Xubuntu 12.04. The "recently used" history is always there after I tried using Activity Log Manager to clear all history.

In addition, BleachBit and Activity Journal both do not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the file `$HOME/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`